# Page number formatting

Tags: page-numbering

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
top=3.5cm, 
bottom=2cm, 
left=3.5cm, 
right=2cm, 
headsep=1.5cm,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents 
    \newpage
\section{INTRODUCTION}
\subsection{Background}
LOREM IPSUM is a graphical bla bla bla and is a bla bla bla that starts with nothing but that.
\begin{itemize}
\item Coverage and Difficult to Interact: Wii wand is not interactive enough and works effectively only within the projected screen space which makes interacting with the screen difficult and not intuitive
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Page numbers are to be placed two centimeters from the top and right hand
margins on the page and must be 12 point. I have managed to get the page numbers to the right, I also have list of figures, list of figures and first page of table of contents, in these, the page numbers are being shown in default foot center.

Comment: You can place elements in then headers and footers using packages like `scrlayer-scrpage` or `fancyhdr`. Package `showframe` helps in understanding where the header/footer starts/ends.

Comment: I have edited the MWE, I need some specific margin of 2cm at top and right of the page number, how does one achieve with fancyhdr?

Comment: use `geometry` package like `\usepackage[leftmargin=2cm,rightmargin=2cm,paperwidth=8in,paperheight=10in]{geometry}`.

Comment: I need to use a separate margin for the page number, in my MWE, the margins are for the overall document. Can I not specify a page number margin exclusively?

Comment: What corner of the page number bounding box should be considered?

Comment: The page number ought to be in the right side, with 2 cm distance from top and right of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page number is already at 2cm from the right margin. In order to move it up, just add `headsep=1.5cm`, so its base will be at 2cm from the page margin. If it's the top that should be at 2cm from the page margin, then use

```
headsep=\dimexpr1.5cm-8.1pt\relax,
```

in the code that follows, because 8.1pt is the height of a digit for the Times font at a 12pt font size.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
  top=3.5cm,
  bottom=2cm,
  left=3.5cm,
  right=2cm,
  headheight=14.5pt,
  headsep=1.5cm,%%%%%% or headsep=\dimexpr1.5cm-8.1pt\relax
]{geometry} % must go before \pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}% better than times

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no rule
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\section{INTRODUCTION}
\subsection{Background}
LOREM IPSUM is a graphical bla bla bla and is a bla bla bla that starts with nothing but that.
\begin{itemize}
\item Coverage and Difficult to Interact: Wii wand is not interactive enough and works effectively
only within the projected screen space which makes interacting with the screen difficult and not
intuitive
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the `times` package is deprecated. Use what I added or `mathptmx`.

Comment: My table of contents is messed up, take a look at the MWE I have posted. I have edited my document based on your suggestions!

Comment: @tilaprimera You need `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}` (or remove the call to the package altogether).

Comment: How do I know if my font for the page number is 12 pt or not?

Comment: @tilaprimera It's in the same font size as the rest of the text.